# For how long does an Easy Card remain active if not used?

Tags: public-transport, transportation, payment-cards, taiwan

Does Taiwan's Easy Card get deactivated if one doesn't use it for a while? How long does it take for the  card to get deactivated? What happens to the balance that remains on the card? Can the card be reactivated, and if so, is there any fee for doing this?

Comment: Multiple secondary sources indicate that the EasyCard will be deactivated upon two years of inactivity, the balance will remain, and the card can be reactivated when you add value to it. I can't find a primary source for that yet, hence this is a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The card is valid until you refund it:

> The Easycard does not expire.
>
> The EasyCard will be valid until it is refunds.
>
> Please check the balance before you use it.

(From an email with them)

Answer (score 1):

(This answer is based on information available from Sep 2021)

According to [EasyCard's website](https://www.easycard.com.tw/introduction?id=4), an EasyCard will (soft) expire 20 years after it is first issued.

While the card will temporarily lock for further transactions, one can extend their EasyCard for free in Taipei Metro stations, convenience stores (7-Eleven, Family Mart, Hi-Life, OK Mart) with counter service, and EasyCard customer service centres. The balance within the card will still be there.

In older times, the card will be temporarily deactivated after two years of inactivity, though they can be reactivated by simply topping up 100+ NTD -- see, e.g., [this 2007 Liberty Times article](https://news.ltn.com.tw/news/local/paper/141949).

---

This is what the [EasyCard website](https://www.easycard.com.tw/introduction?id=4) says (English translation mine):

> Q：為什麼會過期?
> 悠遊卡由於其物理特性、天線老化..等因素，有效期限設定為20年。卡片如果在使用時顯示到期，代表您已經使用20年了，為避免感應不良使用效果不佳，建議您更換新卡使用。

> Q: Why does [an EasyCard] expire?
> The validity of an EasyCard is set to 20 years due to the card's physical properties, ageing [RFID] antenna, and so on. If the expiry message pops up during use, you have already used the card for 20 years.
> We recommend getting a new card to prevent bad card reads.

> 除悠遊卡有毀損或鑒於悠遊卡之物理特性(如生命週期) 無法順利感應等情況外，悠遊卡如顯示到期或過期時，持卡人得至指定地點進行悠遊卡展期，展期後即可再延展5年效期

> The cardholder can extend their EasyCard in specified locations when the screen indicates the card is expiring/has expired unless the card is already broken or cannot be read. The extension is for 5 years.

> 卡片過期了怎麼辦
> 別擔心，只要至下述地點請櫃檯服務人員進行票卡展期，卡片就可以繼續使用，而且卡片中的餘額也不會因此消失喔!
>
> 1. 四大超商門市結帳櫃台（7-ELEVEN、全家便利商店、萊爾富、OK超商）
> 2. 台北捷運各站點（含加值機台及旅客詢問處）
> 3. 悠遊卡公司客服中心（含委外客服據點）[點我查詢](https://www.easycard.com.tw/service)

> What should I do if the card has expired
> Do not worry. You can continue to use the card as long as you extend the card validity in the following locations:
>
> 1. All checkout counters in 7-Elevens, Family Marts, Hi-Lifes, and OK Marts
> 2. All Taipei Metro stations (including top-up machines and information counters)
> 3. EasyCard customer service centres (including outsourced centres) [Click me for locations](https://www.easycard.com.tw/service)
>
> Please approach any counter-service staff for help.

Note: Not all railway stations in the Greater Taipei Area belong to Taipei Metro. Some belong to Taoyuan Metro (e.g., the Airport line), New Taipei Metro (e.g., the Circular line and trams), and Taiwan Railway Administration.

> Q：請問悠遊卡到期後，卡片裡面的餘額會不會不見？
> A：卡片餘額不會因票卡到期而消失，請不用擔心！
> 但卡片到期將無法搭乘交通運具或進行小額支付，建議您儘速持卡至指定地點進行票卡展期，以便繼續使用悠遊卡功能。

> Q: Would the balance on an EasyCard disappear upon expiry?
> A: Do not worry -- the card balance will not disappear upon expiry. However, you cannot take any public transport or pay using an expired card. We recommend you extend your card validity in specified locations to continue enjoying EasyCard functionalities.

> Q：請問悠遊卡到期後展期，會不會有額外的手續費？
> A：悠遊卡展期免手續費用。

> Q: Is there any fee to extend an expired EasyCard?
> A: There is no fee for card extension.